# Overriding form title in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a Symfony form built with

```
class BracketCommandForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    //...
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'bracket_command_form';
    }
}
```

When this form is rendered, it comes with this heading-like `<legend>New bracket command</legend>` with the actual form below it.

**Goal**

I want to override the legend, without changing the name of the form or anything else. Can this be done? If so, where?

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: If it's before the form then that's probably something in your template

Comment: No, it's rendered as part of the `{{form_start(form)}}`, and the only occurences of the title is in cached files, and nowhere in the source files.

Comment: This is in your twig Template. the block name should be "bracket_command_form_widget" something like that

Answer (score 0):

That text didn't came from your `FormType` class, it is passed from the `Controller` (by default in `newAction` function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new BracketCommandForm (), $command, array(
        'show_legend' => true, //false if you don't want the legend at all
        'label' => 'My Text',
    ));
```

Alternatively, I believe you could have this as part of the defaults for that form

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'label' => 'My Text',
        ));
    }
```